# How to get the sum from nested stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8 streams, I am unable to get the correct output from the nested loop operational sum.

In the nested loop, I am calling a method which is returning an integer; by this doing finally summing up the resultant total

This is what I tried:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.IntStream;

    public class NestedLoop {

        public void callTask(int i, int j) {
            System.out.println("i:"+i+"j:"+j);
        }


        public int getCount(Count count, String j) {
            if(count.getCount() >= 123 && count.getCount() <= 125) {
                System.out.println("###");
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }



        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<Count> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
            List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

            Count count = new Count(121);
            Count count1 = new Count(122);
            Count count2 = new Count(123);
            Count count3 = new Count(124);
            Count count4 = new Count(125);
            list2.add(count4);
            list2.add(count2);
            list2.add(count3);
            list2.add(count1);
            list2.add(count);

            NestedLoop loop = new NestedLoop();
            list1.add("list2 - Op1");
            list1.add("list2 - Op2");
            list1.add("list2 - Op2");
            list1.add("list2 - Op2");
            int _count = 0;

          IntStream res = list2.parallelStream().flatMapToInt(x -> IntStream.of(list1.stream().mapToInt(y-> loop.getCount(x,y)).sum()));
          System.out.println(res.sum());
        }
    }

Count class   
    class Count {

        private int count;

        public Count(int count) {
            super();
            this.count = count;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public void setCount(int count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

    }
```

By this, I am getting 12 instead of 2.

Help, me where the code is faulty.

Comment: What is your use case? Why you are expecting 2 as the result?

Comment: @Ravindra, getCount is conditional basis output in my case; that's why I added dummy condition

Comment: Answer 12 is correct here. Please dry run the code and see.

Answer (score 1):

Please dry run the code and see first, because 12 is the correct answer. For each element in `list2` you iterate `list1` and then call the `getCount`, summing the values. For the value 123 it is called 4 times, same for 124 and 125. Each returns 1, summing them all 1 * 3 * 4 yields 12. Why you need 2? What is the rationale?

Anyway is this what you are asking for? This still yields 3, based on your `if` statement.

```
int sum = list2.stream()
        .mapToInt(x -> list1.stream().map(y -> loop.getCount(x, y)).findAny().orElse(0))
        .sum();
```

However, your existing solution which yields 12, can further be simplified like so,

```
int sum = list2.stream()
    .flatMapToInt(x -> list1.stream().mapToInt(y -> loop.getCount(x, y)))
    .sum();
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I have no Idea about streams. thanks for snippet